# large result set of mysql select query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

What would be the easiest way to split an sql file of 80mb into multiple smaller sql files?
thanks.
dani.

Comment: What do you mean by *sql file*?

Comment: I'm guessing he means the results of his SQL query, not a SQL file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` statements to select a certain number of rows.

For example:

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10
```

gets you the first 10 results of your query.

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

gets you 11-20 from your results set.

Comment: thank you very much !
I'm using a java program and the result of select is so large which makes the memory crashes, so I want to find a way to handle the query's result in a segment by segment format.

Comment: not a problem. if this is the answers your question, please click the checkmark to indicate that it is your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some utilities out there to do the job, here is the first one I found on google http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/ .

If you have trouble importing the file I suggest you import it using mysql client console.